# Datepicker chosen date format to Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, datepicker

I have a Rails 4 app in which we have to present the user with a datepicker but the chosen date displayed should be in `MM-DD-YYYY` format. When sending the date to Rails, ActiveRecord does not recognize the format as, I know, it is expecting `YYYY-MM-DD`. Validations fails (date is not present).

The JS is as follows:

```
$("#some_date").datetimepicker
  pickTime: false
  format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
```

(the display works great with a superb datepicker that appears).

Then my slim template:

```
= f.input :date, as: :string, label: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control', value: @visit.date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') }
p.help-block MM-DD-YYYY
```

If I change the format to `YYYY-MM-DD` it works perfectly and date is saved into PostgreSQL as is, however in the US, the date is usually displayed as `MM-DD-YYYY`.

I also don't want to get too involved with helper methods or converting the date from html inputs on each controller so PostgreSQL is happy. I was wondering if there is some way the date format can be changed as it goes to the backend?

Within my `config/locales/en.yml`, I do have:

```
date:
  formats:
     default: '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap datetimepicker doesn't seem to have the option for an alternative format to send to the server. But if all you need is a datepicker and you don't care about time, you can try JQuery datepicker. It allows you to send one dateFormat to display, and an altFormat to send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, there is a field called [altFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) you can use. The database column doesn’t include time zone information, but the time zone is implicitly UTC. You can use the model method to get the desired format. Instead of saving DB in a specific format I can use model method parse a specific format.

```
def your_date
  self[:column_name].strftime("%m-%D-%Y")
end
```

and also you want to change time according to user time zone before parsing into the format.

```
user_record = db_query.your_date
current_user.zone.parse(user_record)
```

Here are some references might helpful to you.

http://brendankemp.com/essays/dealing-with-time-zones-using-rails-and-postgres/
https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

**PS:**  If you find some other better way plz do post.